# JavaScript deep empty an object

Tags: javascript

Looking for a simple solution to deep clean primitive property values directly on an object, e.g.:

```
var filled = {
   levelOneObj: {
      property: 'primitive'
      levelTwoObj: {
         property: 'primitive value'
      },
      levelTwoArray: ['primitive', 123]
   }
}

cleanPrimitives(filled);


var filled = {
   levelOneObj: {
      levelTwoObj: {
      },
      levelTwoArray: []
   }
}
```

I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is already a solution in a library--, any solutions or help is appreciated

Comment: If you're asking for a library, this is off-topic. If you're asking for code, please post your code so far.

Comment: Yes there is: Recursively iterate over the structure and make the modification.

Comment: How is asking if there is a library function off topic? I don't want to waste time reinventing the wheel, if someone knows of a solution in jQuery, underscore, etc.

Comment: @TaylorMac: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: No, I'm asking for a solution to the problem, and if that is in a method in a commonly used library. A method (e.g. _.cleanObj) a is not a "book, tool, software library, tutorial, or other off-site resource"

Comment: @FelixKling if I we're to rephrase "How do I do this in jQuery", I assume you would have the same problem?? Your premise for criticism is flawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
function clean_obj(obj) {
    for(var k in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[k] == "object"
           && obj[k] !== null
           && !(obj[k] instanceof Array)
           && !(obj[k] instanceof String)
           && !(obj[k] instanceof Number)) {

            clean_obj(obj[k]);
            continue;
        }

        switch(typeof obj[k]) {
            case 'string':
            case 'number':
                delete obj[k];
                break;

            default:
                obj[k] = [];
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var my_obj = {..};

clean_obj(my_obj);
```

Comment: Nice, could there be an issue with typeof (new String('test')) // "object" ?

Comment: And typeof (new Number(123)) // "object"

Comment: I'm not sure if the object's source does

Comment: It should be fine now. Do you want to preserve the objects inside arrays?

Comment: Didn't even think about that!

Comment: I would say yes, I would need it to preserve all non-primitive values